# Difference between Karma and Mocha

Tags: mocha.js, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I am new to the Javascript world, being majorly into OOP. I have tried to look up online for a clear cut distinction between Karma and Mocha but in vain. I know Karma is a Test Runner and Mocha is a unit testing Framework, but Mocha also has its own driver and can be used for running tests in the browser. That said, I don't understand what Karma brings to the plate, and why are people using these in conjunction.

Answer (score 30):

Imagine the following scenario:

- Write your own test suites with `Mocha`
- Use `Karma` to run programmatically your `Mocha` tests cross-browser and
  cross-devices
- More, integrate `Karma` with your Jasmine existing environment
- Even more, integrate `Karma` in your Continuous Integration cycle
- Use a million `Karma` plugin to check coverage, complexity, framework
  stuff, etc...

The power of `Karma` is that it can spawn real browsers - such Chrome or Firefox - to effectively test your code with them.

With `Mocha` you can run it in a `NodeJS` environment or in a webpage.

Comment: To be fair though, you can run mocha in multiple browsers to get the cross-browser effect you list. Karma really shines as a test runner, continuous integration, retesting on file change, ability to use in conjunction with jasmine/qunit, etc

Comment: That is what I am saying, nothing different than you. ;)